# Differences to get GetSystemTimeZones in blazor client and server

Tags: server, blazor, client

Good morning!

I'm trying to get the different time zones with GetSystemTimeZone and use it in a blazor app.

I put the functionalities in a class that the client and server share and when comparing data the getSystemTimeZone function in the client gets me a different number than the server.

I have tried to review language settings, browsers, system, IDE and I have looked for some minimal idea of ​​why this is happening to me. Does anyone have some information? Thanks

A minimum of information where to continue with my doubt

EDIT:
Simply

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList();
```

In server obtein less results than client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: They have very different implementations, Blazor Wasm uses the file `dotnet.timezones.blat` (you can find it in \bin). On Windows iirc you can install additional languages. Maybe ask on SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks, I finally opted to convert the helper to a service to use the same construct on both sides